# Move Listbox item to another listbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Just want to ask this.

I have a jQuery that move listbox item to another listbox. An its working fine the item was remove. Sample: I remove item in listbox A and it was added to listbox B.

But here is now the problem, when I tried to check each item in listbox A, I noticed that all items that was removed was still there. But i can see in my eyes that it was removed. but when I tried to run a code to check each items -  all item that was removed was still there.

Please tell me whats the problem with this. Below is my jQuery code

```
$('#btnRemove').click(
  function (e) {
    $('#lstSelectedCol > option:selected').appendTo('#lstAvailableCol');
    //$(this).remove(); 
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this might help

http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/1/

Comment: Have you got firebug/chrome? You can use it's console to log the available items in the list. I've just updated the code and I think it is working properly. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/2/
When you'll click log button, it'll log the items available in the list to the console.

Comment: I tried it again in my code and it's not working... By the way I'm using ASP.net listbox -

Comment: I think moving ASP.NET listbox item using Jquery is only remove the item but not all attributes i guess